# How to protect shape angles when resizing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Working with an oblique square (made from a regular square through `Skew`). I want to make it wider but want both height and angles to stay the same. Resizing with `Shift` saves angles, but height changes also. Does the solution exist in Photoshop, and if yes - how to do it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to grab a side and drag it.

[image]

The transform bounding box will not work, as you've discovered.

Comment: Wow, looks like magic :)